# Entity Framework - association issue

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have an entity framework Complex Type(Activity) I have mapped to a SP which returns records of data.

class Activity 
  string viewed
  string registered

I need to create another another EF entity (complex type?) that will hold metadata about this object and as well as the object data - a List, but I don't know how to make this association(List).

class ActivityData
   string totalrecords
   string pages
   List records

I would need to serialize this Activity class to a webget response in json. Similar to this:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public Activity GetActivity(string total_records, string sql_params)
{
    List<activity> activityList;
    using (ModelEntities context = new ModelEntities())
    {
        resultList = context.CallSP();
    }
    ActivityData data = new ActivityData();
    data.totalrecords = 10;
    data.pages = 5;
    activity.records = List<activity>;

    return activity;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Few problems:

- Complex types cannot participate in relations. So you cannot have complex type which has navigation property to set of other complex types or entities as well as you cannot have entity which has navigation property to set of complex types.
- Stored procedures are not able to populate relations.

Both your `Activity` and `AcitivityData` must be mapped entities (that usually mean they must be either tables or views in database) and you must use Linq if you want to load activities and their data in single database roundtrip.

You will also have use [serialization attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163270/wcf-rest-service-wont-return-children-of-entities/9165228#9165228) to ensure that your relations are serializable to JSON.